# Angularjs ng-click inside ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on a proof of concept where I am using angularjs. I have to use a click function on the links for which I am using ng-click. This ng-click is inside ng-repeat. I went through so many solved problems here in stackoverflow on how to use ng-click inside ng-repeat. But somehow, none of the solutions worked. Can some one help me to point out where I am doing the mistake?

```
HTML Code :

<collection collection='tasks'></collection>
<collection collection='articleContent'></collection>   

app.directive('collection', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            collection: '='
        },
        template: "<ul><member ng-repeat='member in collection' member='member'></member></ul>"
    }
});

app.directive('member', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            member: '='
        },
        template: "<li><a href='#' ng-click='getArticleContent(member.itemId)'>{{member.title}}</a></li>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (angular.isArray(scope.member.tocItem)) {
                if(scope.member.hasChildren == "true")
                    {
                    for(var i=0;i<scope.member.tocItem.length;i++){
                        if(scope.member.tocItem.title) {
                         scope.member.tocItem.title.hide = true;
                        }
                        }
                    }
                element.append("<collection collection='member.tocItem'></collection>"); 
                $compile(element.contents())(scope)
            }
        }
    }
});

app.controller('AbnTestController', function($scope) {
    var bookId ="";
    $scope.tasks = data;

    $scope.getArticleContent = function(itemId){
        alert('inside article content');
        $scope.articleContent = articleData[0].articleContent;
    }
});
```

on click of the link, getArticleContent method is never called here.

Comment: You are using using isolated scope. How can you expect it'll work without binding with scope parameter ?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi. I am new to angular js. I am not much familiar with scope concepts. I used $parent.member.itemId. Even then, it was not working. Is that what you are telling?

Comment: It's isolated scope it won't take anything from parent or to parent without binding with scope

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi. Ok. Then what could be the best way to tackle this?Can you please help me with this.

Comment: Well isolated scope is always recommended but you should choose scope type according to your business. Make your scope `false`  your code will work and also same for scope `true` . Please learn more before taking any  decision which to choose.

Comment: Well, I was forced to use angular :)  basically I am a JSF guy

Answer (score 1):

Directive member has it's own scope, meaning isolated scope.
And the template has an ng-click to execute getArticleContent, that the member directive does not contain the getArticleContent function.

You have two choices:

1. Add the getArticleContent function to the directive member.
2. Create member directive without isolated scope.
   There are issues with this though, having two instances of the same directive may cause conflicts.

Updated after OP comment:

I'm adding OP code with some data passed to directives for manipulation:

```
app.directive('collection', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            collection: '=',
            articleData: '=',
            articleContent: '='
        },
        template: "<ul><member ng-repeat='member in collection' member='member' article-data='articleData' article-content='articleContent'></member></ul>"
    }
});

app.directive('member', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            member: '=',
            articleData: '=',
            articleContent: '='
        },
        template: "<li><a href='#' ng-click='getArticleContent(member.itemId)'>{{member.title}}</a></li>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.getArticleContent = function(itemId) {
                alert('inside article content');
                scope.articleContent = articleData[0].articleContent;
            }

            if (angular.isArray(scope.member.tocItem)) {
                if (scope.member.hasChildren == "true") {
                    for (var i = 0; i < scope.member.tocItem.length; i++) {
                        if (scope.member.tocItem.title) {
                            scope.member.tocItem.title.hide = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                element.append("<collection collection='member.tocItem'></collection>");
                $compile(element.contents())(scope)
            }
        }
    }
});

app.controller('AbnTestController', function($scope) {
    var bookId = "";
    $scope.tasks = data;

    $scope.getArticleContent = function(itemId) {
        alert('inside article content');
        $scope.articleContent = articleData[0].articleContent;
    }
});
```

It would be more helpful if OP can create a jsfiddle for us to review and revise.

Comment: You meant to say I have to use like app.directive('getArticleContent',function()) ??